# Trying to develop on forge 1.12 using the mdk in eclipse. getting error with just base imported project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, casting, minecraft-forge

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    ... 6 more
```

The java version it uses according to environment settings is internal with the mdk.

Comment: You need to run that code with Java 8, it won't work with later versions of Java.

Comment: I don't understand the java the code is using is included in the development kit its 1.8. is there something i need to do to get it to run on another version?

Comment: That stack trace shows you are running the code using Java 9 or later. You must use a Java 8 JRE/JDK  to run the code.

Comment: so apparantly it was running in 15. thanks for the help ill try to get 8 set up and see if i can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that code with Java 8, it won't work with later versions of Java. – greg-449

Make sure you check what jre eclipse is using